# Is there BottomNavigationBar for CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter

Can I make BottomNavigationBar for CustomScrollView such as SliverAppBar as Appbar in CustomScrollView?

When I scroll down to hide it and then scroll up to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I use those widgets in this way in an application, I hope it's helpful!

```
              return SafeArea(
                child: Scaffold(
                  body: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      title: Form(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          maxLines: null,
                          autovalidate: true,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                            _searchProduct(value);
                            _inputCodeController.text = "";
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                          keyboardType: keyboardTypeFix,
                          controller: _inputCodeController,
                          autofocus: _autoFocusInputCode,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                              hintText: 'Barcode'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      floating: true,
                      snap: true,
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _addProductVarious(context);
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.crop_free), onPressed: _scanQR),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new SliverPadding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      sliver: SliverList(
                          delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                              buildItemsViews(_cartItemList))),
                    )
                  ]),
                  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                    onPressed: _closeCart,
                  ),
                  floatingActionButtonLocation:
                      FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
                  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                          child: Text(
                            _cartTotalText,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
```

Comment: For "When I scroll down to hide it and then scroll up to show it." use floating and snap in true